# ssh configuration does not load on boot

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a Ubuntu Server 14.04.
Recently I decided to configure ssh so that only users on the local network can log in to my server. So I added this at the bottom of to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

ListenAddress [server LAN IP address]

And I restarted the ssh service.
Everything works fine. No outside connection requests are accepted and only can log in from terminals in the same LAN.

However, when I reboot the server, all connection are refused even the ones from LAN terminals. I have to physically log in to the server and just restart the ssh service for things to go back to normal (The ssh service does start after reboot, but it just refuses all incoming connections). As if the config file is not loading after reboot?

Below is the sshd_config file
Any help is appreciated.

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

ListenAddress 10.0.0.114
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the `sshd_config` file?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Done. Thank you.

Comment: What are ownership and permissions of the `sshd_config` file?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni -rw-r--r-- 1 root root

Comment: Can you see something in `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni It is empty. auth.log.1 has logs from last November.

Comment: Any idea here @OrtomalaLokni? I am still stuck on this. IDK why it was downvoted either.

Comment: Try to connect with `ssh -vvv` and add the output to the question.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Output
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "10.0.0.114" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.114 [10.0.0.114] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.114 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.114 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I noticed today that when server starts, checking the service status says that it is running but does not show process number. However after restarting the service, and checking status, a process number is shown. Not sure if that means anything. The debug(-vvv) info doesn't show much (see above)

Comment: Try to see if the port is open with `nmap -p22 10.0.0.114`.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Looks like that is the issue:
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh